# Misplaced Auto-generated Facebook page

Tags: facebook

Auto generated Facebook page is misplaced.The wiki description,photos and Facebook posts(99%) are related to another place rather than one on map. The name of the city is **[Poti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poti)**, which locates in Georgian and not in Brazil.

Moreover, the people at that place are marked as they were in Brazil(in Facebook iOS app, friend nearby)

[This](https://www.facebook.com/places/113528518660021/) is the correct page of the city(except bizarre name P'ot'i.

And [This](https://www.facebook.com/places/112164002129015/) page has no coherence to wiki data, and the people tagged on this place are from Georgia,as it is the first result in place suggestions

How can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by taking control of the auto generated Facebook page and editing the false information yourself.

- If you don't yet have a Facebook page for your business, you can **[claim](https://www.facebook.com/help/168172433243582)** the auto generated one
- If you already have an official Facebook page that you have control of but you want to get rid of the "false" one, you can **[request a merge](https://www.reshiftmedia.com/merge-facebook-pages-faq/)**

Comment: I don't have any page on Facebook and it's not for my business as it the page for the city.